# Delete entire project from docker registry?

Tags: docker

How do I delete an entire project from a private docker registry.
It doesn't seem to be documented.

Answer (score 1):

While it is still not easy to do (see [docker-registry issue 45](https://github.com/docker/docker-registry/issues/45)), it should be easier in the new project [**`docker/distribution`**](https://github.com/docker/distribution).

It offers a clear [API to delete images](https://github.com/docker/distribution/blob/e16c23bb434ac3f8c4d65cbf8fa83b9f5a2141d4/docs/spec/api.md.tmpl#L659-L674)

> An image may be deleted from the registry via its `name` and `reference`.
>   A delete may be issued with the following request format:

```
DELETE /v2/<name>/manifests/<reference>
```

Comment: i'm getting 400 "The operation is unsupported.", guess it's not yet implemented..

Comment: @milan it depends: are you using docker registry? or docker distribution?

Comment: local registry, v2, pulled today (b4ad0b763f11)

Comment: @milan ok, so yes, it must not be implemented yet. See https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/422

Comment: ah, bummer, was browsing the code, seemed like it was added https://github.com/docker/distribution/blame/0355c3026c92dc48abe10d232f3ed69f9a2f5bfe/registry/handlers/images.go:  `return handlers.MethodHandler{
35   "GET":    http.HandlerFunc(imageManifestHandler.GetImageManifest),
36   "PUT":    http.HandlerFunc(imageManifestHandler.PutImageManifest),
37   "DELETE": http.HandlerFunc(imageManifestHandler.DeleteImageManifest),
38  }`